How to disable Commit Graph tooltip (popup) in VS Code GitLens extension?
Every time I hover over a commit on the Commit Graph of VS Code's GitLens extension, a huge and annoying popup shows up. Is there a way to disable this? I cannot see anything underneath, cannot even click on the commits because of it.
The image of the commit graph is shown below.


related settings? gitlens.views.formats.commits.tooltip, gitlens.hovers.enabled

What you want is to disable Commit Graph tooltip.
Set gitlens.views.formats.commits.tooltip setting to empty string.
You can do that via Settings UI or by editing settings.json:

Go to Settings
Click on Open Settings (JSON) button in the top right corner
Add "gitlens.views.formats.commits.tooltip": "" line

